# Grouby_concat Metabase MySQL

Tags: mysql, metabase

I am trying to merge the same ID's together, and create a column with all the values in Client Custom Field__value. I cant seem to be able to use groupby_concat correctly.

Here is the original SQL:

```
SELECT `clients`.`id` AS `id`, `clients`.`name` AS `name`, `clients`.`created_at` AS `created_at`, `Client Custom Field`.`value` AS `Client Custom Field__value`
FROM `clients`
LEFT JOIN `client_custom_field` `Client Custom Field` ON `clients`.`id` = `Client Custom Field`.`client_id`
WHERE `clients`.`type` = 'client'
LIMIT 1048575
```

Here is the one I edited to group:

```
SELECT `clients`.`id` AS `id`, `clients`.`name` AS `name`, `clients`.`created_at` AS `created_at`, groupby_concat(`Client Custom Field`.`value`) AS `Client Custom Field__value`
FROM `clients`
LEFT JOIN `client_custom_field` `Client Custom Field` ON `clients`.`id` = `Client Custom Field`.`client_id`
WHERE `clients`.`type` = 'client'
GROUP BY `id`
LIMIT 1048575
```

I get this message:
execute command denied to user 'base_prd_metabase_read'@'10.192.2.6' for routine 'base_prd_system_baseservice.groupby_concat'

I added a picture for visual representation. First time using MySQL, so a easy explanation and reasoning is highly appreciated!

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT4Oo.png)

Comment: `groupby_concat` - no such function in MySQL.

Comment: Do you mean [group_concact](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)?

Comment: @CanO'Spam Yes.